# How to send data from an activity to a class extending PagerAdapter

Tags: java, android

Github code: https://github.com/jjvang/AnimationDemo

Hello, I'm not sure if this is possible but I want to send new data from the main activity to my class which extends PagerAdapter. This app is just a simple demo of a ViewPager having a custom adapter.

I currently want to Click a button on the main activity and the information for the ViewPager would then change to the new ones.

I understand how to send info from one activity to another using intents but this doesn't seem the same since its not going to a new activity.

Please advise.

Thank you!

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
        ViewPager viewPager;
        customSwip  customSwip;
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            viewPager=(ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
            customSwip=new customSwip(this);
            viewPager.setAdapter(customSwip);

            Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
            button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // SOMEHOW PASS THESE DATA TO customSWIP to set new values
                    int [] imageResources ={R.drawable.capture1,R.drawable.capture2,R.drawable.capture3,R.drawable.capture4,R.drawable.capture5};
                    String[] imageText = {"new", "two", "three", "four", "five"};
                    String[] imageHmong = {"new", "new", "new", "new", "new"};
                }
            });

        }
    }
```

customSwip:

```
public class customSwip extends PagerAdapter {
        private int [] imageResources ={R.drawable.capture1,R.drawable.capture2,R.drawable.capture3,R.drawable.capture4,R.drawable.capture5};
        private String[] imageText = {"one", "two", "three", "four", "five"};
        private String[] imageDifferent = {"61236", "612361", "612361", "612361", "612361"};
        private Context ctx;
        private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;

        public customSwip(Context c) {
            ctx=c;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return imageResources.length;
        }

        @Override
        public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
            layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) ctx.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            View itemView=layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_custom_swip,container,false);
            ImageView imageView=(ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.swip_image_view);
            TextView textHmong=(TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.different);
            TextView textEnglish=(TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.english);
            imageView.setImageResource(imageResources[position]);
            final String dummytext = imageText[position];
            textHmong.setText(imageDifferent[position]);
            textEnglish.setText(imageText[position]);
            container.addView(itemView);
            imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Toast.makeText(ctx, "" + dummytext, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
            return itemView;
        }

        @Override
        public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {

        }

        @Override
        public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {

            return  (view==object);
        }
    }
```

Comment: If customSwip class is already set in activity and you want to send data on button click of activity then you can use interface.

Comment: What do you mean by using interface? I went ahead and googled it and most stuff came up about transferring data with fragments. Do you happen to have any reference material via websites?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create a pojo class for all the data you want to show in adapter.like imageresource, text.
now here YourData is that pojo class.
So now you are using same data in adapter as well as in adapter.
Create a constructor of customSwip with the data you want.

```
public class customSwip extends PagerAdapter {
YourPojo yourPojo;
    private int [] imageResources ={R.drawable.capture1,R.drawable.capture2,R.drawable.capture3,R.drawable.capture4,R.drawable.capture5};
    private String[] imageText = {"one", "two", "three", "four", "five"};
    private String[] imageDifferent = {"61236", "612361", "612361", "612361", "612361"};
    private Context ctx;
    private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;

    public customSwip(Context c,YourPojo yourPojo) {
        ctx=c;
        this.yourPojo=yourPojo;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return imageResources.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
        layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) ctx.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View itemView=layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_custom_swip,container,false);
        ImageView imageView=(ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.swip_image_view);
        TextView textHmong=(TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.different);
        TextView textEnglish=(TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.english);
        imageView.setImageResource(imageResources[position]);
        final String dummytext = imageText[position];
        textHmong.setText(imageDifferent[position]);
        textEnglish.setText(imageText[position]);
        container.addView(itemView);
        imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(ctx, "" + dummytext, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
        return itemView;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {

    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {

        return  (view==object);
    }
}
```

And create a method in adapter.
  When you click on button in MainActivity call method using adapters object in which you can update the viewPagers data.

Comment: Sorry, I've been trying to figure it out for an hour now but I don't quite fully understand your solution due to my lack of understanding. I have added as you suggested a constructor of customSwip but don't really know what to do with it. By the way, do I add that in the main activity or incustomSwip? I believe it should its customSwip so I added it there. I have created some getters but I'm not really setting anything so again I'm a bit lost. Please advise again. @MuhibPirani

Comment: create a pojo class for all the data you want to show in adapter.

Comment: I understand what you mean now and it works to an extent, it has some drawbacks but I think I can figure it out from here. Thank you very much